# Is there a way to keep Javascript files private in a Django project?

Tags: javascript, django, stripe-payments

I have a Django project where I would like to accept Apple Pay payments.

I followed a tutorial that uses Stripe with Javascript to process the payments. The Javascript is responsible for rendering the Apple Pay button, as well as using several functions to actually process the payment.

Naturally, my javascript file ended up being public because it was in my static folder. However, I need to pass a secret key into one of these functions.

Is there a way I can rearrange my project so that the Javascript file is private? Alternatively, is there a way to make some of my functions private so that I don't have to worry about hackers stealing my key from my static files?

Comment: Are you referring to the publishable API key used to identify your website with Stripe?

Comment: @IainShelvington no I'm referring to the secret key

Comment: You shouldn't need to use your secret key on the client side, can you link to the tutorial that's telling you to do this?

Comment: It was this video here.... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5KcdQboA7Gc&t=36s&ab_channel=StripeDevelopers I guess I've realized I'm not worried about exposing the secret key, rather I'm worried about the fact that someone could potentially access my clientSecret value. Do you know if this is an issue? In my project I've created an endpoint that technically anybody could access to create clientSecrets. Is that an issue?

Comment: The only key you need on the client side is the publishable key, there is no issue exposing this key as it can only be used on your website and is essentially useless to anyone else. Never expose the secret key though

Comment: So there’s no issue with having a client secret exposed to the customer it corresponds to, right? @IainShelvington

Comment: You can store it in your Backend and get it using API or any kind of get request, and as others mentioned never store any sensitive data or private keys on client-side

Comment: Is this just a simple javascript file of Frontend app?

Answer (score 0):

As Iain Shelvington mentioned, you should only include Publishable Key in your frontend code (Well its name is "publishable"). Secret key on the other hand should only be in your backend code and never exposed to your client. Stripe Doc has a [summary page](https://stripe.com/docs/keys#obtain-api-keys).